# Digg-like search result ranking with Lucene / Solr?

Tags: full-text-search, lucene, solr, digg, reddit

I'm using Solr for search.

I have documents that have an integer field "*popularity*".

I want to rank results by a combination of normal fulltext search
relevance and popularity.

It's kinda like search in digg - result
ranking is based on the search relevance as well as how many digs a
posting has.

I don't have any specific ranking algorithm in mind. But is this
something that can be done with solr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solr's FunctionQuery is exactly what you need:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: would be good if you could add an example your self based on the original question :)