# Limit number of result in SOLR by score

Tags: java, solr

My catalog has a lot of products, so sometimes there are a lot of search results by some queries. Solr have its own field 'score', and our customer wants to limit search results by limiting 'score' value. For example, if we set 'limit score value' to 500, then in search result should be only products which score > 500. (I know this is a bad practice). 
I tried google a lot on it, tried to edit edismax and etc.

So my question, how can i do this?

Comment: NEVER DO THAT ! :D A fq clause like `fq=score:[500 TO *]` doesn't work?

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. "msg": "undefined field: \"score\""

Comment: Did you try it in Solr admin?

Comment: yes, i did it there :)

Comment: Why do you not limit rows?

Comment: as far as i know i can limit rows displayed on page. can i limit overall row count?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I limit by score before sorting in a solr query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382245/how-can-i-limit-by-score-before-sorting-in-a-solr-query)

Comment: I'd guess the customer wants that in order to reduce the number of irrelevant results that are retrieved on some queries. So you probably need some relevance tuning on your queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work because the scores are not consistent. They only make sense within a single query and do not have good absolute representation. They are not even consistent between different cores that form a single collection in SolrCloud. You will not be able to find the meaningful number to use.

You need to go back to the business and ask what they mean **in business terms** and then see how the Solr can answer that. In some cases that may even mean different indexing strategy.